# C# - How to properly use All extension method

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having a problem with this code:

```
foreach (var newRecipient in productTaskEntity.ProductTaskRecipient)
{
    if (existingRecipients.All(i => i.EmailAddress != newRecipient.EmailAddress &&
        i.RecipientTypeId != newRecipient.RecipientTypeId));
    {
        existingProductTask.ProductTaskRecipient.Add(newRecipient);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to loop through the existing recipients collection and see if there's a match on a record with the same email address and recipient type and if there is not, add the new recipient.  Somehow the condition is always evaluating to true, and the recipient is being unneccessarily added.  I think I'm misunderstanding how 'All' works.

Comment: After fixing the semicolon issue... semantically, what you want is `!existingRecipients.Any(...)` with `==` tests. Either will work but it reads better as "if there are *not Any* that match, add it".

Comment: If people just listen to the compiler... C# gives a warning **Possible mistaken empty statement** if you do things like that.

Comment: Team policy: eliminate all warnings (without suppression, that is).

Comment: The title of the question doesn't correlate to the question itself. [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the semicolon `;` after the if. It terminates the if and the next statement is always executed because it is no more part of the if.

```
if (existingRecipients.All(i => i.EmailAddress != newRecipient.EmailAddress &&
    i.RecipientTypeId != newRecipient.RecipientTypeId)); // <=== REMOVE THIS ";" !
{
    existingProductTask.ProductTaskRecipient.Add(newRecipient);
}
```

In C# the if-statment is defined as

```
if (condition) statement
```

This means that the if is always only associated to one statement. E.g. in

```
if (condition) statement1; statement2;
```

only `statement1` belongs to the if-statement. If you need to execute a series of statements, use a compound statement:

```
{ statement1; statement2; ... }
```

like this

```
if (condition) { statement1; statement2; ... }
```

Note also that in C# there is a so called empty statement. In

```
statement1; ; statement2;
```

there is an empty statement between `statement1` and `statement2`. The empty statement does nothing and is only a syntactical artifact. If you write

```
if (condition);
```

then the if-statement if followed by an empty statement.

Comment: Man, that's just embarassing.  Thanks, needed another set of eyes

Comment: `;` hide and seek champion since 1958